# What does the comma signify in Williams equation for finding a longitude given radial and distance?

Tags: trigonometry

In Williams 'great circle' navigation formulae, what is the meaning of the comma in the equation for finding a longitude given a radial and a distance value?

(Williams, https://www.edwilliams.org/avform147.htm#LL)

$lon = atan2(sin(tc)*sin(d)*cos(lat1),cos(d)-sin(lat1)*sin(lat))$

For example, does this mean that $sin(d)$ is to be multiplied by a vector $(cos(lat1), cos(d))$ ?

Answer (score 1):

[Atan2(y,x)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) is a function provided in many program libraries.  It takes the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of a point and returns the polar angle.  It is nicer than the usual arctangent function because it avoids division by zero and it figures out which quadrant the point is in from the signs of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Two arguments determine result better than one (atan) . The (atan2) removes ambiguity of where the vector tip is being placed... in first or third quadrants for positive argument or in second  or fourth quadrants for negative argument (including both possibilities for infinity).